# Aggregate functions are not allowed

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select id, city, address, price, status 
from Apartments 
where price >  avg(price) and status = "Not rented" 
order by price
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему выводится ошибка

Comment: Потому, что вы не изучили групповые функции полностью:-) У вас нет группировки (`GROUP BY`), как среднее-то считать? Читайте учебник внимательно про эту тему (я серьезно, сам так недавно делал, тут все излагать нет смысла). И про `WHERE` и `HAVING` почитайте. `AVG` нечего делать во `WHERE`. + Почитайте про оформление кода - все маленькими буквами и без разбиения на строки (тут я разбил вам) плохо читается.

Comment: @Сергей *У вас нет группировки (GROUP BY), как среднее-то считать?* Ну вообще-то при отсутствии GROUP BY весь набор записей считается одной группой - так что в этом моменте никаких проблем нет.

Comment: *почему выводится ошибка* Потому что агрегатные функции недопустимы во WHERE, который выполняется до группировки, т.е. когда агрегатов ещё не существует. `avg(price)` следует посчитать в отдельном подзапросе.

Comment: @Akina, да, верно, спасибо.  Я смешал `WHERE`, о котором тоже написал, и отсутствие `GROUP BY`.